# Help vote on answers to good questions

Tags: discussion, voting, answers, data-explorer

Sometimes a question gets asked, someone takes the time to respond, but the answer never receives any votes. Sometimes those answers can be quite good, and it would be nice to reward those answers with upvotes.

Would you like to help vote on these answers to older questions? If so, I can suggest a way. Run the following query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/cstheory/query/889195/search-for-question-with-positive-score-where-all-answers-have-zero-score

Then click on some of the links in the results (you can sort by question score first if you want), and take a look to see if the answers are good. This looks for questions where the question score is > 0, where there is at least one answer, and where all answers have a score of 0 (which usually means the answer was never voted on; sometimes for good reason, but sometimes because a nice answer was overlooked).

Thanks to [@D.W.](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1512/37257) for this idea.